# Is it possible to read custom fields added to an Event if the signed-in user is not the organizer?

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit, microsoft-graph-toolkit

We are developing an app that will work inside Microsoft Teams and Outlook.

**Tools we are using:**

TypeScript / React

[Microsoft Teams Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/teams-toolkit-fundamentals)

[Microsoft Graph Toolkit (MGT) React components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/mgt-react)

[Fluent UI React Components](https://react.fluentui.dev/?path=/docs/concepts-introduction--page)

[Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)

**What does the app do?**

The app lists meetings (Events) for the signed-in user. It also allows for creating new meetings and editing them. We need to add some "custom data" to each meeting that our client requires (i.e.: customized "user roles", etc.)

**What's blocking us?**

When the signed-in user is the one who created the meeting -the "organizer"- there is no problem in visualizing and editing the custom data for the meeting.

When signed in as one of the meeting attendees -not the "organizer"- we can not view the custom data added to the event.

We tried adding custom data to a meeting (Event) with both [Open Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/opentypeextension-post-opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and [Schema Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schemaextension-post-schemaextensions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) .

In both cases, we can add extended data to an Event Resource but we are not able to read those fields when we are not signed in as the Event organizer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.